# "onDrag" event not getting triggered in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
<div className="kat-project-user-timeline-drag-indicator-wrapper-bottom"
     onDrag={(event) => {this.dragTask(event)}}>
</div>

dragTask(event) {
  console.log("logic goes here")
}
```

The function is not getting called for the first time. But from second time it is working fine. I tried using, event.preventDefault(), but still it is not working.

Comment: When you state: `The function is not getting called for the first time`, do your logic do anything with a click? also, are you moving (dragging), or just pressing the div without moving mouse/finger?

Comment: I'm also running into this problem - the very first time I drag an element no drag event is fired, but it is then fired on the second time without fail.

Amala - are you using jQuery on the same page? I've not been able to find any answers after spending several hours on this, so now I'm trying to eliminate scripts to see if there is any interference.

Comment: @jacobedawson i found the issue. I was using a library for drag and drop which was overriding my function call for the first time. it worked when i removed the library. I am not using jQuery but react.js

Comment: is the problem resolved after removing the library? @AmalaJames, you could vote to close the question as not reproducible / fixed.

Answer (score 36):

Try adding `draggable="true"` and see if that works:

```
<div draggable="true" className="kat-project-user-timeline-drag-indicator-wrapper-bottom"
 onDrag={(event) => {this.dragTask(event)}}>
</div>

dragTask(event) {
  console.log("logic goes here")
}
```

Comment: It does not help

Comment: this was answered two years ago

Comment: sorry if that came off wrong, i didn't mean it in the wrong way!

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels It wasn't. I overreacted to frequently seeing people scolded for posting activity to old content.

Comment: For mobile compatibility, I had to use both `onDrag` and `onTouchMove` with `draggable="true"`

Answer (score 0):

Make the element draggable and Try onDragStart().

```
    <div className="kat-project-user-timeline-drag-indicator-wrapper-bottom"
draggable={true} onDragStart={handleOnDrag}>
    DRAGGABLE ELEMENT 
    </div>
```

Comment: how is this answer supposed to help OP? Imagine you were OP and you read this answer...

Answer (score -1):

1. Set the ondragstart event too, to the same function set to onDrag event
2. set draggable="true".